# I can't get my Elmah email filters to work

Tags: c#, .net, elmah

I have a query about the following web.config setup and Elmah. The problem is that it I still get emails regarding the public action method issues when I don't want to. The filters I have in place don't seem to be working.

I am not entirely sure how the ANDs and ORs are supposed to work in Elmah email filtering, especially as this code is snipped from some project work I have taken onboard from other developers.

The  tags are meant to prevent any errors from being reported via email that contain any of the words Index, cache or Login.

Can anyone help?

```
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <!--Elmah sectionGroup-->
        <sectionGroup name="elmah">
            <section name="security" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.SecuritySectionHandler, Elmah" />
            <section name="errorLog" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorLogSectionHandler, Elmah" />
            <section name="errorMail" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorMailSectionHandler, Elmah" />
            <section name="errorFilter" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterSectionHandler, Elmah" />
        </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>  

 <elmah>
<errorLog type="Elmah.XmlFileErrorLog, Elmah" logPath="~/App_Data" />
<errorMail from="" to="" subject="Error(Elmah)" async="true " />
    <security allowRemoteAccess="1"/>
<errorFilter>
  <test>
    <or>
        <is-type binding="BaseException" type="System.InvalidOperationException" />
</or>
<or>
    <regex binding="Exception.Message" pattern="(?ix: \b potentially \b.+?\b dangerous \b.+?\b value \b.+?\b detected \b.+?\b client \b )" />
</or>
<or>
    <regex binding="Exception.Message" pattern="(?ix: \b public action method     'Index' was not found on controller \b )" />
    <regex binding="Exception.Message" pattern="(?ix: \b public action method 'cache' was not found on controller \b )" />
    <regex binding="Exception.Message" pattern="(?ix: \b public action method 'Login' was not found on controller \b )" />
</or>
  </test>
</errorFilter>
  </elmah>  
  <location path="elmah.axd">
  </location>  
  <system.web>
  </system.web>
 <system.webServer>    
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
<add name="ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah" />
<add name="ErrorMail" type="Elmah.ErrorMailModule, Elmah" />
<add name="ErrorFilter" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterModule, Elmah" />
</modules>
<handlers>
  <add name="httpHandler" verb="POST,GET,HEAD" path="elmah.axd" type="Elmah.ErrorLogPageFactory, Elmah" />
   </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `test` element can only have one child assertion so having multiple `or` elements underneath it means all but the first are being ignored. From your description, it seems your `test` element should instead read like this:

```
<test>
  <or> 
    <is-type binding="BaseException" type="System.InvalidOperationException" /> 
    <regex binding="Exception.Message" pattern="(?ix: \b potentially \b.+?\b dangerous \b.+?\b value \b.+?\b detected \b.+?\b client \b )" /> 
    <and> 
      <regex binding="FilterSourceType.Name" pattern="mail" />
      <regex binding="Exception.Message" pattern="(?ix: \b public \s action \s method \s '(Index|cache|Login)' \s was \s not \s found \s on \s controller \b )" /> 
    </and>
  </or> 
</test>
```

Note that I also went ahead and folded the three `regex` elements into one and fixed the pattern to delimit words correctly (`\b` on edges and `\s` inbetween).