# Can't filter "A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client" in elmah

Tags: filter, elmah

I use the official example from the [elmah wiki](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/wiki/ErrorFilterExamples), but this error keeps show up in my log, how can i fix it? following is my elmah configuration, thanks a lot.

```
    <sectionGroup name="elmah">
      <section name="security" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.SecuritySectionHandler, Elmah" />
      <section name="errorLog" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorLogSectionHandler, Elmah" />
      <section name="errorMail" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorMailSectionHandler, Elmah" />
      <section name="errorFilter" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterSectionHandler, Elmah" />
    </sectionGroup>

<elmah>
    <errorLog type="Elmah.SqlErrorLog, Elmah" connectionStringName="elmah" />
    <security allowRemoteAccess="yes" />
    <errorFilter>
        <test>
                <regex binding="Exception.Message" pattern="(?ix: \b potentially \b.+?\b dangerous \b.+?\b value \b.+?\b detected \b.+?\b client \b )" />
        </test>
    </errorFilter>
</elmah>
```

Comment: I found the answer on another thread.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10799538/i-cant-get-my-elmah-email-filters-to-work

Answer (score 0):

You might be missing the HTTP modules?

```
<httpModules>
...
<add name="ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah"/>
<add name="ErrorFilter" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterModule, Elmah"/>
...
</httpModules>
```